# Differential operator continuity

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $$A: = {\partial _x}:{L^2}(0,L) \to {H^{ - 1}}(0,L)$$
and $$B = :{(1 - \partial _x^2)^{ - 1}}:{H^{ - 1}}(0,L) \to H_0^1(0,L)$$
How can I show that $A$ and $B$ are continuous? I know that$${\partial _x}:{H^1}(0,L) \to {L^2}(0,L)$$ is continuous, but I have no idea about how treat this problem with dual space.. Thnaks.

Comment: How do you define the $H^{-1}(0,L)$. Are the functions periodic or is it simply the dual of $H^1(0,L)?$

Comment: for the operator $A$ $H^-1$, is the dual of $H_0^1(0,L)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Boundedness of $A$.** We want to prove that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$\|Af\|_{H^{-1}}\leq C\|f\|_{L^2},\quad\forall \ f\in L^2(0,L).$$

Let $f\in L^2(0,L)$. Then $\partial_xf\in H^{-1}(0,L)$ with
$$\langle\partial_x f,\phi\rangle=-\int_0^Lf(x)\phi_x(x)\;dx,\quad\forall\ \phi\in H_0^1(0,L)$$
and thus, by the Hölder's inequality,
$$|\langle\partial_x f,\phi\rangle|\leq\|f\|_{L^2}\|\phi\|_{H_0^1}, \quad\forall\ \phi\in H_0^1(0,L).$$
This implies that
$$\|Af\|_{H^{-1}}=\sup_{\phi\in L^2\\\phi\neq 0} \frac{|\langle \partial_x f,\phi\rangle|}{\|\phi\|_{H_0^1}}\leq \|f\|_{L^2}$$
which proves the desired result.

**Boundedness of $B$.** As above, we can show that the linear bijection $$(1-\partial_x^2):H_0^1(0,L)\to H^{-1}(0,L)$$ is continuous. So, the desired result follows from the [Bounded Inverse Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem) (also called [Banach Isomorphism Theorem](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wc3BDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA155&dq=%22banach+isomorphism+theorem%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXwJnPp5HUAhUGFZAKHTSmAegQ6AEIVzAG#v=onepage&q=%22banach%20isomorphism%20theorem%22&f=false)).